# Removing tick marks, tick=FALSE do not seem to work

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to make a plot in r where the x-axis is time stamps from the vector called `time`.
The values in `time`:

```
[1] "04:00:00" "06:00:00" "08:00:00" "10:00:00" "12:00:00" "14:00:00" "16:00:00" "18:00:00" "20:00:00" "22:00:00" "24:00:00"
```

However, the plot still put the values 2, 4, 6 and so on in between the time stamps?
The code I use for the plot:

```
sumH1<-plot(tempsSumH1, type="l",xlab="Time",ylab="Temp")
axis(1,at=1:11,labels = time,tick = FALSE)
```

How the plot actually looks:
[image: Plot with tick marks.]

Note that the even numbers do not necessarily need to be replaced with the time in the vector but can be left completely empty.

Comment: You should set `xaxt = "n"` in your `plot()` command

Comment: @Lennyy Okay thanks, the one I found about ticks on stack was the one that told me to set ticks=F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `plot` command generates an entire plot, and then the `axis` command *adds* something to the existing plot. It does not alter what is already there. The numeric labels are drawn by the `plot` command, and you can hide them by setting `xact = 'n'`.